# No such iterable when trying to join strings with Java String.join

Tags: java

This question was not caused by a typo. I did not realize that there was no function overload which takes a char as well as a string. I also did not realize that a char would not be converted to a string in a function call. Finally, I did not realize that char and string were two strongly differenced types.

So no, it's not a typo - I just don't know Java.

---

The following code snippet, which I am fairly confident should work

```
String[] arrayBootstrapServers = {
    "server1.com:9093",
    "server2.com:9093"
};

String stringBoostrapServers = String.join(',', arrayBootstrapServers);
```

produces the following error when compiling

```
[ERROR] ... no suitable method found for join(char,java.lang.String[])
[ERROR]     method java.lang.String.join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; char cannot be converted to java.lang.CharSequence)
[ERROR]     method java.lang.String.join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.lang.CharSequence>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; char cannot be converted to java.lang.CharSequence)
```

Why?

Comment: `','` is not a `CharSequence`, but a `char`. A string such as `","` is a char sequence.

Comment: Also, what does "no such iterable" mean? It is not part of the compiler error message.

Comment: @knittl It is from the compiler message

Comment: I don't see it in the compiler message which you have posted. Nevertheless, this is a typo (and knowing that methods in Java must be called with arguments of the correct type)

Comment: @knittl See the answer I posted for the resolution

Comment: Yes, the error is still caused by a typo `","` != `','`

Comment: @knittl It's not a typo. They are two completely different types.

Comment: @knittl One is a char, one is a String. Comeing from other languages, you would usually expect to be able to join with either, but apparently not in Java.

Comment: I cannot think of a programming language where a string and a char is equivalent and can be used interchangeably. Can you give an example?

Comment: @knittl most languages would typically provide an overload to String.join functions to permit both types. Alternatively, Python is one example. `','` and `","` are the same. A string. Javascript is yet another example.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant - I am puzzled as to how you got up to 12K rep and not realise that this is considered a typo in the review queues ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I started using Java for the first time literally a few days ago. If you bothered to look at my reputation, you should also have bothered to look at some questions I have asked before, and from this you would quickly realize that I am a specialist systems engineer and almost exclusively work with C++.

Comment: @RohitGupta By the way high rep does not equal good software engineer or Computer Scientist. There are many people with many times more reputation than I personally have, but they cannot tell you what a linked list is.

Answer (score 1):

You could change in this way. The first parameter type of "String.join" is "CharSequence", not "char".

`String stringBoostrapServers = String.join(",", arrayBootstrapServers);`

Answer (score -3):

It's got to be a string, not a char.

```
String.join(",", array);
```

`','` is a char, `","` is a string. Apparently in Java, one cannot call String join with a char argument as the delimiter, as a string is required instead.

Comment: "It's got to be a string, not a char." Well, it's got to be a `CharSequence`. There are implementations of `CharSequence` other than `String`. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)).

Comment: (And in general, when a method call doesn't work as expected, the documentation should be the first place you look, IMO.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You assume I didn't look at it? Why else would I say "I believe this should work".

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't look at it before asking the question, yes - otherwise why ask the question at all? ("I can't call a method with arguments that aren't appropriate for any of the overloads" isn't really a useful question, IMO. And it would be *really* odd to ask a question including code that you're "fairly confident should work" if you've already looked at the documentation and seen that it really shouldn't...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added a couple of lines to my question to explain for you what my confusion was. Hopefully this will convince you that I did indeed look at the documentation, misunderstood it, and hence why it was the case I thought this should work when it didn't. Not sure quite why this matter is so important to you however.